# Number of badges overlaps 'badges' label on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, design, badges, stackexchange.com, network-profile

[Jon Skeet](https://stackexchange.com/users/11683/jon-skeet?tab=accounts) broke yet another thing: the network profile. His number of bronze badges is shown ... suboptimally ... on stackexchange.com:

[image]

Tested on macOS Big Sur 11.5.2, the latest Firefox and Safari. Browser width doesn't seem to matter (stackexchange.com isn't responsive yet).

Comment: It's fine for me, even when I make my screen skinnier (which just adds a scrollbar). What's your device specifications?

Comment: Reproducible on Firefox Nightly 93.0a1. Works fine on Chromium 92.0.4515.159. Window size is irrelevant because the size of that table is fixed and non-responsive.

Comment: Looks like the font size of the digits appears a bit smaller in Chrome, despite the `font-size` being the same `15px`. But of course, it will be broken _cross-browser_ once Jon reaches 10000 bronze badges or silver badges, or 1000 gold badges.

Comment: Looks like it's OS-related, not browser-related. No repro on both Chrome (92.0.4515.159) and Firefox (91.0.2) on Windows.